# Search a SO post that I closed with a certain keyword

Tags: feature-request, support, search, data-explorer

Is there a way to search for a Stack Overflow post that I closed and that has a certain keyword say "this" or certain code say `this` in it?

I mean, I want to search by typing in the search bar something like:

```
user:783380 is:question          "this"
                         ^^^^^^^---------->what should come in this blank space
```

In the above query I have left some space indicating what should come there something like `votes:closed` or `votes:deleted`.

Is this doable? I want to search for a post that I, say, closed or deleted and that contains a specific keyword.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the on-site search to find posts that you closed.

You can find posts that are closed by using the `closed:1` search option.
You can find your posts by using the `user:me` search option.
When you combine those you get questions that you wrote and are now closed.

For your specific search requirement we have to turn to the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/help).

The PostHistory table holds in rows with typeid 10 close events and then record the close voters as a JSON blob in the Text column.
In SQL Server we can use OPENJSON to query over that blob. Combining all that in a [query gives us this:](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1621918?search=this&UserId=811)

```
select p.id as [Post Link] 
     , p.creationdate
     , p.score
     , p.owneruserid as [User Link]
from posthistory ph
inner join posts p on p.id = ph.postid
cross apply openjson(ph.text,'$.Voters') with (userid int '$.Id') as voters 
where ph.posthistorytypeid = 10 -- closed
and voters.userid = ##userid:int?811##
and p.body like concat('%', ##search:string##, '%')
```

When run today for a well known close voter we get this result:

[image: result for userid 811 and term "this" showing around 600 question titles]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Never forget that [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) created the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).